# After generating the exe it does not execute

Tags: python

good evening

I am Brazilian and I am using the translator to answer the question, sorry if the wrong words are coming out.

My project manages Windows services and for that I created an interface using a separate '.kv' file and I also use a CSV to be able to read the names of the services.
However, after running main.spec I can't run the exe from the Dist folder.

Could you help me find out?

Attached is the main.spec and main code

note: I'm new to programming!!

main.spec :

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Gabriel Da Silva\\Desktop\\Python Estudos\\Kivy\\Projeto-TotvsServices3'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('services.csv', 'TotvsServices3.kv')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,Tree('kvArq\\'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='main')
```

main.py:

```
##Projeto de aplicativo gerenciador de serviï¿½os do Windows
##

import kivy
from kivy.uix.label import Label
kivy.require('1.11.1')

import win32.lib.win32serviceutil 
import csv
import fileinput
import os
import kivy.utils

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew


class TelaPrincipal(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):

        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        linha = ''
        groupName = ''

        with open('services.csv','r') as arquivo_csv :

            leitor = csv.reader(arquivo_csv, delimiter=';')

            for linha in leitor :

                if(linha[0] == 'Group'):
                    self.addServiceGroup(linha[1])
                    groupName = linha[1]
                else:
                    self.addService(linha[0],linha[1],groupName)

        self.atualizaService()

    def addServiceGroup(self,name=''):

        group = ServiceGroup(name)

        self.ids.corpo.ids.body.add_widget(group)

    def addService(self,name='',displayName='',nameGroup=''):

        for i in self.ids.corpo.ids.body.children:

            if(i.id == nameGroup):

                i.add_widget(Service(name,displayName))

    def atualizaService(self):

        service = win32.lib.win32serviceutil

        for i in self.ids.corpo.ids.body.children:

            for s in i.children:

                if(s.id == 'service'):
                    print( 'Atualizando... ' + s.name)
                    s.ids.LbService.text = s.displayName + ' - ' + s.StringStatus(service.QueryServiceStatus(s.name)[1])



class Corpo(ScrollView):
    pass 


class ServiceGroup(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, name='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.id = name

    def OptionRunGroup(self,Tipo=0):

        for i in self.children:

            if(i.id == 'service'):
                i.OptionRun(i.name,Tipo)
                print('RunOption' + str(self.id) + str(Tipo))


class Service(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, name, displayName,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.displayName = displayName
        self.id = 'service'

    def OptionRun(self,NomeServico='',Tipo=0):

        service = win32.lib.win32serviceutil

        if(Tipo == 1):

            if(service.QueryServiceStatus(NomeServico)[1] == 1):

                service.StartService(NomeServico)
                print(NomeServico + ' ' +str(Tipo))                            
        elif(Tipo == 2):

            if(service.QueryServiceStatus(NomeServico)[1] == 4):
                service.StopService(NomeServico)
                print(NomeServico + ' ' +str(Tipo))

        self.ids.LbService.text = self.displayName + ' - ' + self.StringStatus(service.QueryServiceStatus(NomeServico)[1])

    def StringStatus(self,nService=0):

        if(nService == 1):
            return "STOPPED"
        elif(nService == 2):
            return "START PENDING"
        elif(nService == 3):
            return "STOP PENDING"
        elif(nService == 4):
            return "RUNNING"
        elif(nService == 5):
            return "CONTINUE PENDING"
        elif(nService == 6):
            return "PAUSE PENDING"
        elif(nService == 7):
            return "PAUSED"





class TotvsServices3(App):

    def build(self):

        return TelaPrincipal()

# Execuï¿½ï¿½o
if __name__ == "__main__":
    TotvsServices3().run()
```

Comment: Can you tell me what error you are getting when you try to run the exe? (Você pode me dizer qual o erro que está recebendo ao tentar executar o exe?) (Sorry if this is wrong, I used Google Translate)

Comment: No error appears, double click and do nothing

Comment: don't double click but run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see error messages - this helps you to see which element you may have to add to `main.spec` when you create .exe file.

Comment: Yes, @furas is right. Try that.

Comment: something is wrong with the code, because even running the exe on the console it will not
I tried to create a simple python file like print('Test') and when it generates the exe it doesn't appear on the console, is there anything I should know?

Comment: and what if you put `print()` in many places to see which code is executed ? What if you create script only with `print()` - without `Kivy` ? Is this displaying text when you run it in console ?

Comment: So, when I did the print () test I did it in a code with nothing, just it, without kivy and without anything else.
but in my code I sent above it is already full of prints ().
Do you have a code example with an example main.spec?